# Use Azure Monitor Metrics to get the average daily compute minutes

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, azure-monitor, cost-optimization

in my Azure architecture I would like to scale down a couple of web app services.

I would like to use the D1 tear, which has a limited consumption time of 240 min/daily (as you can see in the picture below).

My question is: how can I use the Azure Monitor Metrics tool to get the average compute time for the last 30 days?
Maybe the CPU Time?

I'm asking that because I don't know if those web services work less then 4 hours a day.
Thanks for reading

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question! You may want to know that Azure App Service provides built-in monitoring functionality for web apps in the Azure portal from the Azure portal, you can review quotas and metrics for an app and App Service plan, and set up alerts and autoscaling rules based metrics.

If the app is hosted in D1 that is Shared plan, the limits on the resources that the app can use are defined by quotas.

Check [Understand quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#understand-quotas) and [Monitoring quotas and metrics in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#monitoring-quotas-and-metrics-in-the-azure-portal)

Let us know if further query.